Words duplication: that very one
Could You please tell me if it sounds weird to use two pronouns in one phrase:
"...rising and falling on the waves, waiting for that very one"
In context: there is a surfer who literally lives surfing, and waits his whole life for that special super wave that comes once in a century.

"that very one" is not idiomatic here, unless there was something earlier in context to justify "that very", such as the surfer seeing a wave in the distance and thinking "this is the wave I've been waiting for all my life" or something like that.

I think it's perfectly idiomatic. very here is an intensifier, but that one* clearly refers to what OP calls that special super wave that comes once in a century. And since it's a well-known trope that serious surfer do live in hopes of being able to ride that particular wave (albeit semi-fictitious), I have no problem with ...waiting for that very one provided the context has already established that the subject does in fact have that ambition.

We need more context than part of one sentence.

...waiting for that very one
There are no multiple pronouns;
that is a demonstrative determiner, very is an intensifier, and only one is a pronoun.

Exactly. The intensifier emphasizes that the surfer want to ride the biggest wave of the century - not the second biggest, or just any wave much higher than usual. It's the stuff of legends.

It's a bit dated and poetic, and presumably figurative rather than "literal", but..., Old Ocean heaves that very wave / That bore aloft the Ark
